# Angular UI Router - after child state refreshes, doesn't load css and js files

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need an angular app which is working after moving site to any subfolder.

Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/pictonic/css/pictonic.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/webapp/css/Webapp-font.css">

    <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
    
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="mainView/mainview.js"></script>
    <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
    <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
    <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

State provider

```js
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
     url: "/",
     templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
    })
    .state('parent', {
     abstract: true,
     url: "/parent",
     templateUrl: 'partials/parent.html'
    })
     .state('parent.child1', {
              templateUrl: "partials/parent.child1.html",
              url: "/child1"
          })
     .state('parent.child2', {
              templateUrl: "partials/parent.child2.html",
              url: "/child2"
          })

    .state('etc', {
     url: "/etc",
     templateUrl: 'partials/etc.html'
    })
```

Apache rewrites configured well. If i go to the 'etc' state and refresh everything works fine. But a child state refresh gives error. Browser try to download for example the app.js file from www.mysite.com/parent/app.js when that stays here: www.mysite.com/app.js

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this script in the index.html. To the rUrl write your parent state urls, separate with "|". All of your css and js files will be added with addTag(), so place there your sources.

Apache/nginx rewrites needed!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var indexFile = (location.pathname.match(/\/(index[^\.]*\.html)/) || ['', ''])[1],
          rUrl = /(#!\/|settings|index[^\.]*\.html).*$/,
          baseUrl = location.href.replace(rUrl, indexFile),
          headEl = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
          sync = true;

      addTag('base', {href: baseUrl});

      addTag('link', {rel: 'icon', href: 'images/favicon.png', type: 'text/css'});
      addTag('link', {rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'css/bootstrap.min.css', type: 'text/css'});
      addTag('link', {rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'css/app.css', type: 'text/css'});

      addTag('script', {src: 'js/jquery.min.js' }, sync);
      addTag('script', {src: 'js/angular.min.js' }, sync);     
      addTag('script', {src: 'js/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js' }, sync);
      addTag('script', {src: 'js/angular-ui-router.min.js' }, sync);
      addTag('script', {src: 'js/app.js' }, sync);
      
      function addTag(name, attributes, sync) {
        var el = document.createElement(name),
            attrName;

        for (attrName in attributes) {
          el.setAttribute(attrName, attributes[attrName]);
        }

        sync ? document.write(outerHTML(el)) : headEl.appendChild(el);
      }

      function outerHTML(node){
        // if IE, Chrome take the internal method otherwise build one
        return node.outerHTML || (
            function(n){
                var div = document.createElement('div'), h;
                div.appendChild(n);
                h = div.innerHTML;
                div = null;
                return h;
            })(node);
      }
    })();
    
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but I'd look into the way you set the base tag. If you set the base as your current location, then `..src="app.js"...` should actually take your location into account. Of course this only gets set once on page load.